# Bootstrap 4 Center Navbar Brand and Links

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So right now I have the basic setup with my nav brand on the left side and the links on the right. What I would like is to center all of it and have the Nav brand above the links. So ideally it would look like this

```
                                     Brand
                           link link link link link
```

Ive tried following what it says on bootsrtap but maybe its not working because thats now on alpha6 and I'm using alpha3.

Here is my navbar.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
 <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#nav-content">
       &#9776;
    </button>
       <a class='navbar-brand' href='/'>
          <span><%= image_tag("logo_white_background", :size => '30x30', :alt => "Test" ) %></span>
          <span class='light'>Test</span>
        </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: "nav-link #{yield(:blog_active)}" %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Test', tag_path("test"), class: "nav-link #{yield(:test_active)}" %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Test', tag_path("test"), class: "nav-link #{yield(:test_active)}" %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Test', tag_path("test"), class: "nav-link #{yield(:test_active)}" %>
            </li>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

This is my nabber.scss (not including things like font and color

```
@media(max-width:61.9em) {
.navbar .navbar-brand {float:none;display:block;}
.navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item { float: none; margin-left: .1rem;}
.navbar .navbar-nav {float:none !important;}
.nav-item{width:100%;text-align:left;}
}
```

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/